Kotlin "Cannot set property because no setter, no wither and it’s not part of the persistence constructor" Error
I have object A like this:
sealed class B {
private val d: String = this::class.simpleName!!

data object C: B()
}

data class A(
val b: B,
)

And I have faced this error when I want to get object A from the database:
Cannot set property d because there is no setter, no wither and it’s not part of the persistence constructor private B$C()

What is the problem?
I just want to save the value d in the database something opposite of @Transient annotation. What can I do instead of what I have done?

maybe check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76986804/10702209
